# Add a class to the sections once they are visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

This is how I am trying but the condition would never fire..

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
            $('section').each(function(){
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                var bottom = top + $(this).height();
                if(top <= scrollTop && bottom >= (scrollTop + vieportHeight) ){
                    $(this).addClass('visible');
                    console.log('Hola');
                }else{
                    console.log(top,bottom,scrollTop,viewportHeight);
                }
            });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYeMC/

Any idea whyat i'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/ a good plugin which is doing what you want!

Comment: There is a typo here and in your jsfiddle: vieportHeight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the typo, you have a slight math error. The easiest way I've found to determine if an element is onscreen is to determine the top and bottom of the viewport and compare that with the top and bottom of the element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewport = $(window),
        setVisible = function (e) {
            var viewportTop = viewport.scrollTop(),
                viewportBottom = viewport.scrollTop() + viewport.height();
            $('section').each(function () {
                var self = $(this),
                    top = self.offset().top,
                    bottom = top + self.height(),
                    topOnScreen = top >= viewportTop && top <= viewportBottom,
                    bottomOnScreen = bottom >= viewportTop && bottom <= viewportBottom,
                    elemVisible = topOnScreen || bottomOnScreen;
                self.toggleClass('visible', elemVisible);
            });
        };
    viewport.scroll(setVisible);
    setVisible();
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYeMC/2/

Comment: Hey! I'm back with this functionality, i was trying to make a custom selector to make this feature mor reusable, http://jsfiddle.net/toniweb/GHE52/3/ , any idea why it fails? thanks!!!

Comment: In your handler for "inViewPort", the passed-in parameter "obj" is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so jQuery methods like `offset` and `height` will not work. To fix this, wrap your parameter in a jQuery object or use element properties instead of jQuery methods. http://jsfiddle.net/GHE52/4/

Comment: This is great but is there a way to only have this fire off once on each div?  For example I'd like to scroll through each of them with the class being added but when I go back up, I don't want them to be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/rYeMC/1/

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        $('section').each(function () {
            var top = $(this).offset().top;
            var bottom = top + $(this).height();
            if (top <= scrollTop && bottom >= (scrollTop + viewportHeight)) {
                $(this).addClass('visible');
            } else {
                console.log(top, bottom, scrollTop, viewportHeight);
                $(this).removeClass('visible');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

everything's fine with your code. just correct the typo (vieport) and be aware that the style attribute overrules your external css!

Answer (score 0):

This is the condition

```
if(scrollTop + viewportHeight >= top ){
    $(this).addClass('visible');
}
```